# ¿En PyQt5 cómo puedo hacer un menubar que contenga tanto menulist como flags de windows?

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, pyqt5, pysimplegui

[image: Ejemplo]
Diseño de la interfaz con el menubar integrando banderas de windows y menulist.